OAuth2 to a Custom API with Curl
I try to get a Oauth2 authorisation and tokens to get a API request for this API there:
https://api.hiorg-server.de/docs/courses#tag/Course/operation/coursesGet
I have try anything, what works when I use the composer library, but this doesn't works on WordPress.
Composer code as example:
https://github.com/hiorg-server/api-oauth-starter/blob/main/index.php
Has some one a hint and and help for that?
I like to get a Oauth2 token and a refresher token with a expiration timer to save them into the database. With the token and refresher I can get the course list. For the Token and Refresher, I need a regenerating function.
The best output i get with follow error Authorization Type not supported or {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed","message":"Client authentication failed"}
has some one a hint for that ?
  echo("OAUTH");
    // Step 1: Get the OAuth2 token
    $response = wp_remote_post($token_url, [
        'body' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        ],
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($client_id . ':' . $client_secret),
        ],
    ]);

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        return $response->get_error_message();
    }

    $body = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);

    if (isset($body['error'])) {
        return $body['error_description'];
    }

    $access_token = $body['access_token'];

    // Step 2: Fetch the courses data
    $response = wp_remote_get($api_url, [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $access_token,
        ],
    ]);

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        return $response->get_error_message();
    }

    $courses = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);

    return $courses;

